# Creating network between two docker containers

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and trying to explore it. I have two containers running on a host machine. In the first container I have a mongodb server installed with a base image of ubuntu:18.04 and in the second container l have a binary file of my API code. Now I want to connect with mongodb server, which is running in first container. I tried by creating user-defined network and connect with the name of container but it is not connected. In API code I am using something like this to connect to the mongodb server "mongodb://mongodbconainerName:27017". I have written my code in Go. Any help would be appreciated.

//Dockerfile for api

```
FROM scratch
ADD restfulApis restfulApis
EXPOSE 8080 27017
ENTRYPOINT ["/restfulApis"]
```

//Dockerfile for mongodbserver

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
CMD ["mongod"]
EXPOSE 27017
```

//docker run command

```
docker run -d --net=mynet --name container1 mongodbserver
docker run -d --net=mynet --name container2 apicode
```

Comment: Can you show where you configure the actual connection string?  As you've shown it, the process should be able to connect to `container1`, the `--name` of the MongoDB container.

Comment: Are you able to use docker-compose?

Comment: No I am not able to use it .. But there was problem that mongodb was not binding my apicontainers ip so i use CMD ["mongod","--bind_ip_all"] this solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can using this command for run MongoDB with docker command, not need to use MongoDB over ubuntu image :

```sh
docker run -d --net=mynet --name mymongo -d mongo:latest
```

Comment: but i have given task in which i have to use ubuntu as my base image

Comment: my hitting my api container using curl .. curl -XPOST -d '{some json data}' -url http://apicontainername:8080/todos its not giving me any response means it is not connecting with my mongodbcontainer

Comment: Ok, do you check container logs? ```docker logs -f mongodbserver```

Comment: yes I have checked logs my mongodb server is running and also I checked inside container using "docker exec -it mongodbservecontainer bash" and then i write "mongo" its looking every thing ok inside the container

Comment: move `EXPOSE 27017` command with `CMD ["mongod"]` and check again. you did exposed port after run `mongod`,

Comment: no its not working .. mongodb server is running . there is some networking issue between containers . when i hit simple api container then welcome msg is printing but when i request for data then its not working . even mongodb server is runnin well in its container

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for such task. Here is the simplest way to connect these two containers.

**depends_on**

> Express dependency between services, Service dependencies cause the
>   following behaviors:

- docker-compose up starts services in dependency order. In the
  following example, mongodb will started before apicode.
- docker-compose up SERVICE automatically includes SERVICE’s
  dependencies. In the following example, docker-compose up web also creates and starts MongoDB.
- docker-compose stop stops services in dependency order. In the
  following example, apicode is stopped before mongodb.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example 
    networks:
      - mongonetwork
  web:
    image: "node:alpine"
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - mongonetwork
networks:
  mongonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

> When docker-compose executes >V2 files, it will automatically build a
>   network between all of the containers defined in the file, and every
>   container will be immediately able to refer to the others just using
>   the names defined in the docker-compose.yml file.

In the above case, you will Mongo host will be `mongo` only. see below example
I do not have go runtime, so testing on nodejs here is the simplest code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

The mongo host will be `mongo

Note: with Ubuntu, you will need the following action to make it work.

- Set user name and pass with some script
- Allow connection from other than 127.0.0.1 in /etc/mongo.conf
- You current ubuntu Dockerfile installing `v3.*` which have some [bug](https://github.com/chefsplate/mongo-shard-docker-compose/issues/1) while during connection which is fixed in the later version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need your custom MongoDB image? It is easier if you follow this link - https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mongo#connect-to-mongodb-from-another-docker-container.

Following this, I have tried the followings:

```
# create a docker bridge network of your own
$ docker network create mongodb

# deploy a mongodb server using this network, so that the container name (the hostname) is available to the other containers using the same above network
$ docker run --name mongodb --network mongodb --rm -d mongo:4.0

# Connect to MongoDB from another Docker container
$ docker run -it --network mongodb --rm mongo mongo --host mongodb test
...
> db.getName();
test
>
```

So, it will be also available to you using the address: `mongodb://mongodb:27017/test`

Since, from the 2nd conatainer I could have connected to the MongoDB server running on the 1st container, you can also connect to the server by using proper connection info.

See, its simple.

If you want to deploy a MongoDB server with authentication, then for example I have tried the followings:

```
$ docker run -d --network mongodb --name mongodb \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
    mongo:4.0

$ docker run -it --rm --network mongodb mongo \
    mongo --host mongodb \
        -u mongoadmin \
        -p secret \
        --authenticationDatabase admin \
        test
...
> db.getName();
test
```